# Mockito: wait for stubbing to finish

Tags: spring, multithreading, unit-testing, mockito, integration-testing

I'm building a spring integration test.
In this test I use mockito like this:

```
@MockBean
A mockA;

public void test(){
    when(mockA.a()).thenReturn(1).thenReturn(2);
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Now, there is another bean, on another thread, which constantly calls mockA.a().

The result is an race condition, in which **sometimes** a() will return 1 twice. Thinking about it, it's quite reasonable - the other bean is fast and succeeds to call a() twice before the test thread arrives to the thenReturn(2).

Is there a nice way to make Mockito wait for the stubbing to finish, before it starts returning the values?

Or any other nice solution you can think of?

I don't want to use *sleep*, for it is ugly...

**EDIT:**
The call to mockA is from another bean which uses 'A' bean.
For instance:

```
public class B{
    @Autowired
    A a;

    @PostConstruct
    public void method(){ // This method will
        System.out.println(a.a());
    }
}
```

Comment: The best solution would be to configure your mock where you really need it. But if you use threads it changes everything, plz, provide more details about concurrency in your tests.

Comment: I've edited the question